# I need the second line to always be aligned

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I need the second line to always be aligned, currently it looks like this:

[image]

I need it to be like this:

[image]

I tried to do this using col, but it always bugs depending on some screen size, I need it to be in a simple and responsive way:
This is the initial code

```
<Container fluid style={{width: '100%', border: '1px solid black', backgroundColor: 'white', borderRadius: '10px',
marginTop: '8px', boxShadow: '-10px 0px 13px -7px #000000, 10px 0px 13px -7px #000000, 5px 5px 15px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0)',
WebkitBoxShadow: '-10px 0px 13px -7px #000000, 10px 0px 13px -7px #000000, 5px 5px 15px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0)',
padding: '0px',
}}>
   <Row style={{margin: '0px', padding: sizeWidht < 650 ? '5px 0px 5px 5px' : '10px 0px 
    10px 10px'}}>

       <Col xs={6} md={6} style={{flex: 1, borderRight: '1px solid black', marginBottom: 
       '0px', marginTop: '0px', padding: '0px 0px 0px 5px'}}>
            <P><strong>Name: </strong>{name}</P>
            <P><strong>age:</strong> {age}</P>
            <P><strong>description:</strong> {description}</P>
                           
       </Col>  

       <Col xs={5} md={5} style={{flex: 1, marginBottom: '0px', marginTop: '0px', 
        padding: '0px 0px 0px 5px'}}>
           <P><strong>test:</strong> {test}</P>
           <P><strong>test2: </strong>{test2}</P>
           <P><strong>test3:</strong> {test3}</P>

        </Col> 

   </Row>
</Container>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Set a `className` on the `<strong>` element containing "Name:", "Age:", & "Description:"
2. Use it set `display: inline-block` & `width`.

Comment: This works but on the line break, it is not aligned, is there any solution for this?

Comment: screenshot please